# How to scrape dynamic website?

Tags: screen-scraping

I am a novice website scraper, trying to get a usable list of all past events on Hackathon.io. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I have been using the chrome scraper extension but it comes up empty/blank for this website. Thanks

http://www.hackathon.io/events

Comment: we need to see a tad more effort. perhaps some sample code, even if "loose"

Comment: I tried to attach a screen grab of my scrape results, but it won't let me unless I have 10 reputation. The scrape only shows 20 events/rows even if I keep clicking "show more". Is there anyway to change the xpath to account for all past events?  The current xpath: //div[2]/div/div/div/h4/a

Answer (score 0):

The more button can be enumerated like so: http://www.hackathon.io/events?location=&page=61&term=&time=past&utf8=%E2%9C%93 ; you would just iterate through those and grab the links using the appropriate xpaths.